# How to link to a path inside an a tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to have a button that links to a path.

I've got:

```
%a{:href => "<%= edit_owner_path(current_owner) %>"}
  %input{:class => "add-one", :type => "button", :value => "Upgrade listing", style: "padding: 12px 12px 12px 68px;"}
```

but that is clearly wrong. How else should I express this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%a{ :href => edit_owner_path(current_owner) }
  %input{ :class => "add-one", :type => "button", :value => "Upgrade listing", style: "padding: 12px 12px 12px 68px;" }
```

Comment: if this the right answer for you, you can mark this as right answer also. Thanks.

Comment: I will - but there's a time delay before I'm allowed to award the correct answer.

Comment: not a problem at all. It is all if you think. But you should wait and see for the best answer as well. That is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to 'Upgrade listing', edit_owner_path(current_owner), :class=>'add-one', :style=> 'padding: 12px 12px 12px 68px;'  %>
```

or

```
<%= button_to 'Upgrade listing', edit_owner_path(current_owner), :class=>'add-one', :style=> 'padding: 12px 12px 12px 68px;' %>
```

or in haml

```
= button_to 'Upgrade listing', edit_owner_path(current_owner), :class=>'add-one', :style=> 'padding: 12px 12px 12px 68px;'
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should use link

```
%a{:href => "<%= edit_owner_path(current_owner) %>"}
```

Then style it to look like button, do not mix semantic and what you want to show to user. For your purpose you need link, but how will it look to the end user, it falls inside style.